# How do I open a URL in a web browser from an iOS standalone webapp

Tags: ios, html, mobile-safari, iphone-standalone-web-app

I have a web app that runs in standalone mode on the iPad (using `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />`).
Does anybody know if I can launch a URL in a normal browser from within my app?

Comment: I've tried window.open with _blank, to no avail. It opens up within the standalone app.

Comment: You can do it with <a href='http://foo.com' target='_blank'>bar</a>, or you can do it via javascript by following top voted answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930001/force-link-to-open-in-mobile-safari-from-a-web-app-with-javascript