# Force link to open in mobile safari from a web app with javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, web-applications, mobile-safari, iphone-standalone-web-app

When calling `window.open()` in a iOS web app, the page opens in the web app instead of mobile safari.

**How can I force the webpage to open in mobile safari?**

Note: Using straight `<a href>` links is not an option.

Comment: You mean the <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">Go to SO</a> doesn't work?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This is possible. Tested with iOS5 stand-alone web app:

HTML:

```
<div id="foz" data-href="http://www.google.fi">Google</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("foz").addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.setAttribute("href", this.getAttribute("data-href"));
    a.setAttribute("target", "_blank");

    var dispatch = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    dispatch.initEvent("click", true, true);
    a.dispatchEvent(dispatch);
}, false);
```

Can be tested here: http://www.hakoniemi.net/labs/linkkitesti.html

Comment: But when i want to return value from the opened window then it is not working

Comment: @Napalm make sure to add a semi-colon at the end of the line `var dispatch = ...`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<div id="foz" data-href="http://www.google.fi">Google</div>` - Opening a `<div>` and closing it with a `</a>` doesn't make much sense. And what's the `</li>` at the end?

Comment: @valmar, you're right. This example contained typos, I fixed them.

Comment: doesn't work now? I tried in iphone5 UIWebView, after click, google page is opened in same view, not Safari.

Comment: Does not work for me in the Facebook app browser. I did fix the semi-colon @laker.

Comment: Excellent solution ... and then there was iOS 7 :(

Comment: Does not work with links in Naver Line app.  @chun are you able to share a demo link of it working in iOS7?

Comment: It does not work when the initial event is not a click. For example after a change of a selector, depending of the option selected open a link.

Comment: This works on ios 6, 7 and 8, all android that i've tested (around 6 devices on varying os's), and desktop browsers (chrome,firefox,ie,safari,opera) (when this code is fired from within another touch/click event) (useful for canvas games) when your site is loaded within the facebook mobile app, changing the target to `a.setAttribute("target", FB.UA.nativeApp() ? "_self" : "_blank");` makes the links work, albeit _self! providing you have he facebook javascript included!

Comment: You, dear sir, are a pure genius. May god bless you and your family.

Comment: It seems like this is not possible anymore as of iOS 8.3. Anyone else?

Comment: Tested in iOS 8.3 for a webpage saved to the home screen in webapp mode. Works.

Comment: Worked for me in iOS 8.3 from within a HTML5 full-screen standalone web app. Thanks!

Comment: This only seems to work when going to google.com. Facebook, stack overflow, etc. all open within the gmail app, instead of opening a new safari window. Am I missing something?

Comment: It does not work for me in an iOS 9.2 standalone app. I have the feeling apple has a thing agains standalone apps.

Comment: It works when I've add event listener to div that in document like in example. But when I've try to call this code just from javascript (e.g. on click on webgl button) - it fails to open anything.

Comment: To my prev comment: iOS 10.1, example works OK, but when I've try to call it from click on webgl button instead of div - nothing happends. To solve it just remove "a.setAttribute("target", "_blank");" and use a.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", {'view': window, 'bubbles': true, 'cancelable': true}););. And it opens a new safari window. Absolutely don't know why target=_blank is unnecessary in this case.

Comment: I could not make it work on instagram in app browser on ios, does anyone have a working example?

Comment: This doesn't work for me in iOS 11. It just opens the link within the embedded UIWebView.

Comment: Won't this just open the default browser?

Comment: I was hopeful because of all the upvotes, but this didn't work for my scenario. If I'm browsing my website from within the iOS Facebook app and I click a link written like this, it still just opens within Facebook's browser instead of Safari.

Answer (score 10):

Turns out it is **NOT POSSIBLE** to escape the iOS web app with a JavaScript `window.open()`. If you want a link to open in mobile safari you have to use `<a href>` links.

Comment: care to elaborate? i'd like to have an <a href> link to open safari from chrome / opera on ios

Answer (score 2):

Vue implementation. Hope will helpful.

```
<template>
<div @click='handler()'>{{ text }}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    href: String,
    text: String,
  },
  methods: {
    handler() {
      const a = document.createElement('a')
      a.setAttribute('href', this.href)
      a.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", {'view': window, 'bubbles': true, 'cancelable': true}))
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can force iOS to open a link from PWA in safari using window.open() provided you either use a different sub-domain or use http instead of https.

For example for take example.com

```
window.open('http://example.com','_blank')
```

Note: My server will redirect http to https once opened in the browser. So there is no security concern.

(or)

```
window.open('api.example.com','_blank')
```