# Javascript - Programmatically Click Anchor in iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, html, ios, safari, anchor

I working with an existing website, with some anchors tags like so:

```
<ul>
    <li><a id="answer-1" href="/" rel="0">Answer 1</a></li>
    <li><a id="answer-2" href="/" rel="1">Answer 2</a></li>
    <li><a id="answer-3" href="/" rel="2">Answer 3</a></li>
    <li><a id="answer-4" href="/" rel="3">Answer 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

I need to programmatically click one of these anchors depending on the user's selection.

On the desktop, in IE, this works:

```
document.getElementById('answer-1').click();
```

However, doesn't quite work in iOS safari, this results in a popup:

```
if (!document.getElementById('answer-1').click) alert ('Oh no!');
```

Best I can tell, they have some other javascript hooked up using to send the `rel` tag as an answer.  Is there another way to programmatically click the anchor in iOS Safari?  Or do I need to go digging in their javascript to find out what is being called when the anchor is clicked?

I have also tried this, which doesn't work:

```
window.location.href = document.getElementById('answer-1').href;
```

They must be doing more in Javascript somewhere (maybe jquery).

Comment: The `window.location` is an object. You should set it's `href`-property like this: `window.location.href = document.getElementById('answer-1').href`

Comment: Sorry, I was typing that off the top of my head.  I have adjusted my answer, it does not work.

Comment: This is a safety issue. You can't examine local folders in all browsers.

Comment: What does this have to do with folders?

Comment: `<a href="/">Anchor</a>` opens a folder.

Comment: @Teemu That's incorrect. It will redirect to the root of the current website, not open a folder.

Comment: @sciritai Original question includes this: "On the desktop, in IE, this works:". On a server, just like you said. This also seems odd to me: `if (!document.getElementById('answer-1').click)`. Expression refers to DOM's `click`-method. Events can't be handled thorugh it?

Comment: To clarify: calling `click()` worked fine for me in IE9 on Windows 7.  `if (myControl.click)` also evaluates to true in that browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've answered to a similar question where one needs to dispatch click event manually: [Force link to open in mobile safari from a web app with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930001/force-link-to-open-in-mobile-safari-from-a-web-app-with-javascript/8833025#8833025)

You can apply that logic into your code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the click function is not supported by Mobile Safari. document.getElementById('answer-1').click returns undefined which is why you get the alert. Try using .trigger()

Comment: I'm not sure what version of jquery they have loaded, but I was unable to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like there is not a way to call `click()` in mobile safari.

Using the dev-toolbar in Google Chrome, I was able to figure out the javascript function that is invoked when you click one of these anchors.

I was able to just call the function to get what I need.

I will wait a few days to mark the answer, as I would still like to know an alternative to `click()` in mobile safari.

Answer (score -1):

This problem occurred too with my Mac app when tested under Snow Leopard or Lion. Strangely it worked with Mountain Lion.

I solved the problem using jQuery.

```
$('#answer-1').click();
```

You may also give it a try if the site already loads jQuery!