# How to open mobile webapp link in Safari from native Facebook app on iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook, web-applications, uiwebview, safari

Our webapp works nicely inside the Facebook native iOS app. However, we have some links that need to open a new window in mobile Safari rather than opening inside the Facebook (UIWebView?) app. Just a plain HTML `<a href="http://site...." target="_blank">` doesn't do it--still opens within the Facebook app (latest version.) Any way to get a plain link or a window.open() to switch to Safari for the page load ?

Comment: Does the solution proposed here work - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930001/force-link-to-open-in-mobile-safari-from-a-web-app-with-javascript ?

Comment: Highly dubious. Saw that. I'll try it just to eliminate it as a possibility. The web view is likely UIWebView on iOS running inside the fb app. So <a href target='_blank'> whether statically or dynamically constructed is unlikely to launch a new tab in Safari unless the fb app specifically supports that. So that is really the question--does fb browser support any markup or other hook to do this, same as the UI button 'open link in Safari'.

Comment: @tip, that's irrelevant to the question which is how to open an external link in Safari from an html/js web app running in the fb app native container. Obviously having our own native app is a "solution" but to a different question.

Answer (score 0):

The web team on my company tried that approach and failed. What we ended up doing was using Facebook deep linking to handle this on our native iOS app.

You can find out more about Facebook deep linking here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/link-to-your-native-app-ios-sdk/

It's a great solution if you already have an iOS app.

I hope this helps.