# How to open a link in new window(not in new tab) in Html/css

Tags: javascript, html, css

To open link in new tab you do this:

```
<a href="#" target="_blank">open in new tab</a>
```

But how can I made it open in a new window?

So, help me out to overcome this problem.

Comment: It's very poor UX to decide how and when new windows (or tabs) should open. That decision should be left to the user,

Comment: This is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15766254/458614

Answer (score 1):

i think yo want to open a completely new window on clicking a link.in other words u want a popup.try the following code.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function popitup(url) {
newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150');
if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
return false;
   }
```

```
<a href="popupex.html" onclick="return popitup('popupex.html')">Link to popup</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in theory but it will depend on the preferences set in the browser. Now a days you can fake a new window by using div's and Layers. Is there anyway to implement a layer that hides what is behind it.

JavaScript:

```
function getElementsByClass( searchClass, domNode, tagName) { 
    if (domNode == null) domNode = document;
    if (tagName == null) tagName = '*';
    var el = new Array();
    var tags = domNode.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
    var tcl = " "+searchClass+" ";
    for(i=0,j=0; i<tags.length; i++) { 
    var test = " " + tags[i].className + " ";
    if (test.indexOf(tcl) != -1) 
        el[j++] = tags[i];
} 
return el;
}
// paste getElementsByClass function (see above) here 

function showtab(tabname) 
{ 
// hide every element with class 'box1'  
var tabs = getElementsByClass('box1');
for(i=0; i<tabs.length; i++) {
    tabs[i].style.display = 'none';
    //tabs[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
// hide every element with class 'box1'      
var tabs2 = getElementsByClass('myStyle');
for(i=0; i<tabs2.length; i++) {
    tabs2[i].style.display = 'none';
    //tabs2[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

document.getElementById(tabname).style.display='block';
//document.getElementById(tabname).style.visibility='visible';
// show element with given tabname 
} 

function showsubtab(tabname)
{
//hide every element with class 'myStyle'
var tabs = getElementsByClass('myStyle');
for(i=0; i<tabs.length; i++) {
    tabs[i].style.display = 'none';
    //tabs[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
document.getElementById(tabname).style.display='block';
//document.getElementById(tabname).style.visibility='visible';
}

if (window.addEventListener) { // Mozilla, Netscape, Firefox
window.addEventListener('load', showmessage, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) { // IE
window.attachEvent('onload', showmessage);
}

function showmessage() {
document.getElementById('box').style.display='block';
document.getElementById('div1').style.backgroundColor='grey';
document.getElementById('div1').style.opacity = 0.2;
document.documentElement.style.overflow = "hidden"; //firefox, chrome
document.body.scroll = "no"; // ie only
var bodyLayer = document.getElementById('div1');
DisableLinks(bodyLayer);
}
function hidemessage() {
document.getElementById('box').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('div1').style.backgroundColor='transparent';
document.getElementById('div1').style.opacity = 1.0;
document.documentElement.style.overflow = 'auto';  // firefox, chrome
    document.body.scroll = "yes"; // ie only
var bodyLayer = document.getElementById('div1');
EnableLinks(bodyLayer);
}

function DisableLinks(dom) {
if(undefined != dom){
    links=dom.getElementsByTagName('A');
} else {
    links=document.getElementsByTagName('A');
}

for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
    links[i].style.pointerEvents="none";
}
}

function EnableLinks(dom) {
if(undefined != dom){
    links=dom.getElementsByTagName('A');
} else {
    links=document.getElementsByTagName('A');
}

for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
    links[i].style.pointerEvents="auto";
}
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="box">
<section id="close">
<section id="title">Important Site Message</section>
<section id="button"><a href="#" onClick="hidemessage();">[X]</a>&nbsp;</section>
</section>
<!--Body of the Message-->
</div>
```

CSS
    #box {position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; height: 15.625em; width: 25em; background-color:#FFF; margin-top: -7.8125em; margin-left: -12.5em; display: none; overflow: auto; border-color:#000; border-style:ridge; border-width:medium; z-index: 3; color: #000;}
    #close {border-bottom: inset thick #CCC; background-color: #000; width: inherit; height: 1.2em; color: #FFF; position: fixed;}
    #close a:visited {color: #FFF;}
    #close a:hover {color: red; text-decoration:none;}
    #close #title {text-align: center; font-weight:bold; width: 90%; padding: 1 1 1 1; clear: left; float: left; background-color:#000; color:#FFF;}
    #close #button {text-align: right; padding: 1 1 1 1; width: 10%; clear: right; float: right; background-color: #000; color: #FFF;}

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<a href="#nul" onclick="window.open('newLink.html ','','Toolbar=1,Location=0,Directories=0,Status=0,Menubar=0,Scrollbars=0,Resizable=0,Width=550,Height=400');">Name</A>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function openWin()
{
myWindow=window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
myWindow.focus();
}
</script>
```

Refer more over [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the width and height when you call `window.open`, most browsers will open the link in a new window rather than a tab.

```
window.open(url, '_blank', 'width=500,height=400');
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/VbgbA/)

Answer (score 0):

Use below code
myWindow=window.open('https://www.google.co.in/','','width=500,height=500');

Answer (score -2):

> use`target="_blank"` inside the "a" tag