# Opening new window with JavaScript (predetermined size and width) via PHP echo command

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I have something that looks like this and I am trying to open a new link with predetermined size/with inside a PHP echo. Here is what I have,

```
echo '<a href=“noticeboard.php?charid=' .$row_char['noticeID'].'"STYLE="text-decoration: none" target="_blank"> &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;[Announcements]<br>
```

I have tried :

```
echo '<a href=“noticeboard.php?charid=' .$row_char['noticeID'].'"" onclick="window.open (this.href, 'child', 'height=400,width=300,scrollbars'); return false">W3C</a> &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;[Announcements]</a>
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a easier way to implement this.

Thanks.

Comment: That helps answer the question. 


Thank-you! I have looked for hours on this. I am new to PHP so trying to learn the basics.

Comment: No problem. Just a reminder, if if you find answers on Stack Overflow that help, don't forget to upvote, and marked "solved" to whoever best answered your question :)

Answer (score 0):

As you are not preventing default behavior of  tag, you will not be able to execute **onclick** event of  tag :

Try below changes :

```
echo "<a href=\"noticeboard.php?charid=".$row_char['noticeID']."\" onclick=\"javascript:void(0);window.open (this.href, 'child', 'height=400,width=300,scrollbars'); return false;\">W3C</a> &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;[Announcements]</a>";
```

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` (first in the block) instead of `void(0);[…]return false;` is the better approach in general and especially when giving an example to beginners.

Comment: Yup, **javascript:void(0)** can be replaced with **event.preventDefault()**, Thanks for pointing that out.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Having a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939928/make-a-link-open-a-new-window-not-tab), the following should work. Keep in mind the problem was most likely improper escaping so make sure you keep track of opening and closing quotes and not mixing them up.

`echo '<a href="noticeboard.php?charid='.$row_char['noticeID'].'" onclick="window.open(\'noticeboard.php?charid='.$row_char['noticeID'].'\', \'child\', \'height=400, width=300, scrollbars\'); return false">W3C</a> &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;[Announcements]';`