# open new window popup separate from browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to open a new window but I want it to be a free floating popup separate from the main browser (not in a new tab)
Every example ive found using various javascript/jquery/target="_blank" methods always opens in a new tab.  I want the window to 'float' separately from the main browser

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me, I used this in one of my projects:
https://jsfiddle.net/9o5f9Ls0/2/

```
<a onclick="window.open(this.href, 'test', 'left=20,top=20,resizable=0'); return false;" href='https://www.google.com'>Test</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

See this answer: [Make a link open a new window (not tab)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939928/make-a-link-open-a-new-window-not-tab)

Here is a snippet that does what you're describing.

```
<a href="print.html"  onclick="window.open('print.html', 'newwindow', 'width=300, height=250'); return false;"> Print</a>
```