# How to open links in new browser window using ie 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

Can I open links on click in new browser (**not** a popup) window?

Things I have tried:

```
<a href='http://osric.net/' onclick='return !window.open(this.href);'>osric.net web hosting</a>
```

A function onclick:

```
var windowObjectReference;
var strWindowFeatures = "menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes, toolbar=yes";

function openRequestedPopup() {
  windowObjectReference = window.open("http://www.cnn.com/", "CNN_WindowName", strWindowFeatures);
}
```

but with these it opens in new tab only.

Comment: How are you distinguishing between a "new browser window" and "popup window"?

Answer (score 0):

This works on IE 11:

```
<script>
function popupBrowser(url) {
  window.open(url, "WindowName", "config=menubar=no,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes,toolbar=yes,fullscreen=yes");
}
</script>

<a href="javascript:popupBrowser('http://www.cnn.com')">Open a new browser for IE11</a>
```

It just imitates browser by using `windows.open()`

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7e23ub9u/)

Answer (score -1):

Here it goes

```
<a href="your_link" target="_blank">Visit</a>
```

target="_blank" - is the key

Use this for new window

```
<a href="print.html"  onclick="window.open('print.html', 'newwindow', 'width=300, height=250'); return false;"> Print</a>
```

Ref: [Make a link open a new window (not tab)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939928/make-a-link-open-a-new-window-not-tab)

Comment: But `target='_blank'` does not control wether the window is opened in a tab or in a new window.