# How to open link in new window without _blank page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a webpage with an url to PHP file which displays picture. I want to open this picture in new window **without blank page**.

For now with code below, when I click on URL, blank page and new window open (which I have to close each time). I do not want this blank page, only window with picture

```
window.open('image.PNG', 'image', 'toolbar,menubar,scrollbars,resizable,height=800,width=400,left=600,top=400');
```

How to do it?

//edit
Prevent default does not work if I have

```
<a href="file.php">Link</a> //URL to PHP with script above
```

Comment: use javascript event prevent default and window.open .

Comment: See this link... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939928/make-a-link-open-a-new-window-not-tab

Comment: prevent default does not work in this case

Answer (score 0):

If you paste this in your console:

```
open('image.png');
```

And a new tab opens *with the picture you want*, than try:

```
<a href = 'image.png' id = 'image'>
```

and

```
document.getElementById('image').onclick = funciton(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    open('image.PNG', 'image', 'toolbar,menubar,scrollbars,resizable,height=800,width=400,left=600,top=400');
};
```

If that doesn't work, paste this in your console:

```
open('file.php');
```

And a new tab opens with the *picture you want*, than try:

```
<a href = 'file.php' id = 'file'>
```

and

```
document.getElementById('file').onclick = funciton(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    open('file.php', 'image', 'toolbar,menubar,scrollbars,resizable,height=800,width=400,left=600,top=400');
};
```

If *none of that* works, comment below.