# PHP- How to open a hyperlink in a new window?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to open a hyperlink in a new window instead of a new tab.. This is what I tried..

```
<a href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>/orders/SOprint_new/?id=<?php echo $d['orderID']; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $d['orderID']; ?></a>
```

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939928/make-a-link-open-a-new-window-not-tab

Comment: _blank will open in a tab if that is what the browser is set to do. You need JavaScript with window.open and parameters to open in a new window

Comment: Try to read before you asked a questions. [Read article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939928/make-a-link-open-a-new-window-not-tab)

Comment: @Shubham _blank will always open a tab if the browser is set to open new pages in a tab. window.open with parameters will open a new window

Comment: <a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.open('<?php echo SITEURL; ?>/orders/SOprint_new/?id=<?php echo $d['orderID']; ?>', 'window name', 'window settings')"><?php echo $d['orderID']; ?></a>

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Position_and_size_features

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply change _blank to _new

```
<a href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>/orders/SOprint_new/?id=<?php echo $d['orderID']; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $d['orderID']; ?></a>
```

Comment: It's not working  :/

Comment: There is no _new parameter for target. It just acts as if you had target="whatever". Please refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target

Comment: Never had to use it anyway. Should have pasted JS code I guess. People are so quick to down vote.

Comment: A while ago - browser changed the behavior of _blank to new Tab because it's less annoying for the enduser - but nevermind - you can still do this with JavaScript (be aware, that there could be a "this page uses popups" could occur)

`<a href="http://example.org" target="popup" onclick="window.open('http://example.org','popup','width=600,height=600'); return false;">Open Link in Popup</a>`

Comment: People vote down when the answer is incorrect as yours is. Nothing to do with speed

Comment: @DominikAngerer here is a better one: `<a href="https://google.com" target="myWindow" onclick="var w=window.open(this.href,this.target,'height=600,width=800'); return w?false:true">open</a>`

Comment: Thank you Dominik and mplungjan.