# How to open new window with new session always in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

How to open new window with new session always in IE?

in java-script method i have an `window.open(appurl,'_blank',"height=500,width=500")`

if i call the java-script method, application needs to open in new window with new session(Alt+F+I) in IE browser.

if i call the java-script method once again, application needs to open in new window freshly.should not share the existing window sessions.

Comment: Not sure if you can... Is this a duplicate of this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939928/make-a-link-open-a-new-window-not-tab

Answer (score 1):

As I recall, the trick is to use a unique name every time you open a window. You should also set a unique variable when opening: var win1=window.open(w1..., var win2=window.open(w2... This is so that you can close individual windows in JS.

At the moment, you are naming every window '_blank'. By default this will open a new window, but if you open a second window with the same '_blank' name, the first window gets replaced.

Try keeping a counter and naming windows ...1, ...2 etc.