# Html5 Open a new Window not a popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface

Is there a way to open a link in a new window, not in a popup window or tab.

When I use the below code it open the links as a new window popup.

```
<script>
 function myFunction() {
 window.open("http://www.google.com/", "myWindow", "width=200,height=100");    
}
</script>
```

[image]

But we wanted it as below like a new actual browser window not a window popup.  Is there a way to do this.?

[image: But wanted it as below like a actual new browser window]

I got referred to this link - [Make a link open a new window (not tab)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939928/make-a-link-open-a-new-window-not-tab)
But it doesnt talk about what I am asking here, That question was more on how to open a window than a tab. Here I can open a window but the feeling of that window is like a popup window, Not liked a actual browser window like I showed above

Comment: look for opening a new tab instead

Comment: The requirement is specific to open a new window :(

Comment: Hey is this what you're looking for ? 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939928/make-a-link-open-a-new-window-not-tab

Comment: @JimCiaston - No Actually all the examples are of opening new window than tab. I can open a new window using window.Open, But its coming as popup window rather than a actual window which I referred above

Comment: @LGSon - Can you please suggest why its a duplicate.?

Comment: As stated in the dupe's answers, you can't control whether it is opened in a window or a tab, hence I closed it. Did I misunderstood you? ... or you mean as with `target=_blank` that is used in an anchor `a` element?

Comment: @LGSon - Sorry I opened a new question as it was marked as duplicate :( . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50863732/html5-open-a-new-window-not-a-popup-window-but-a-actual-browser-window

Comment: You do not open a new second, exact same, question because the first were closed.

Comment: What you seem to be considering an "actual" window is exactly the same thing as what you're calling a "popup" window; the only difference is that the "actual" one is  maximized fullscreen. (No, it is not possible to force a window to open fullscreen, that's up to the user.)

Comment: The answer to this question is in the first sentence of the accepted answer of the duplicate question. The answer is **You Can't** and **You should not be allowed**, because it is usually misused e.g. annoying creepy ads.