# Always run Shiny App in same browser window

Tags: r, shiny

Simply question: Is it possible for a Shiny app to be launched in the same browser target window as the previous instance. It becomes quite annoying to have to close all test run windows after a while. I've tried to set a fixed port, but that didn't help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a link open a new window (not tab)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939928/make-a-link-open-a-new-window-not-tab)

Comment: No, the question is not regarding links in the shiny app itself, but the target window in which the app is launched!

Comment: This link might help. Not exactly your question though. The 2 topics here https://deanattali.com/blog/advanced-shiny-tips/#auto-kill-app

Comment: Maybe try setting `runApp(your_dir, launch.browser = FALSE, port = 1234)`. Then the app will be running in the background so from your target window you can type `your_comp_name:1234` to load the page.

Comment: This bugged me for years, searching for an answer to no avail. @MKa suggestion works though, I only add `launch.browser = FALSE` to `runApp()` call and refresh old browser tab.