# Open link in New Window in PHP Echo

Tags: php

How to open link in new window if the output using echo''? I've tried this method https://stackoverflow.com/a/15766254/13981642 but cannot show the output using echo'';

My PHP Code: `echo 'Last Revision: ' . date('F j, Y', strtotime($row['updated_at'])) . '<a href="http://example.com/contact.php">Contact us</a>';`

Thank you

Comment: why does that linked method not work?

Comment: PHP and `echo` have nothing to do with opening windows. PHP is a server-technology. Windows are opened in a browser. Code for doing so is written in HTML and JavaScript - client technologies. The link, that you posted, explains exactly how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The method to which you [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939928/make-a-link-open-a-new-window-not-tab/15766254#15766254) works perfectly well when you escape the quotes properly as shown below with a simple `echo` and an alternative `printf` statement.

Notice that the single quotes within the output string are escaped using a backslash!

```
$row['updated_at']='2022/03/20 08:32:12';
$date=date( 'F j, Y', strtotime( $row['updated_at'] ) );

printf(
    'Last Revision: %s <a href="//example.com/contact.php" onclick="window.open(\'/contact.php\',\'Contact\',\'width=800,height=600\'); return false">Contact us</a>', 
    $date
);


echo 'Last Revision: '.$date.' <a href="//example.com/contact.php" onclick="window.open(\'/contact.php\',\'Contact\',\'width=800,height=600\'); return false">Contact us</a>';
```

Comment: It's worked thank you. I've another question how to make injection PHP in link tag after contact.php?feedback='. $row['page_id'] .' ?

Answer (score 0):

Add target="_BLANK" in an anchor tag it will redirect to new tab

```
My PHP Code: echo 'Last Revision: ' . date('F j, Y', strtotime($row['updated_at'])) . '<a target="_BLANK" href="http://example.com/contact.php">Contact us</a>';
```