# Open safari ios from chrome/mozilla ios

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, safari

i have created a page which is optimized for iOS Safari, now i want to add a link on my page to redirect the user to the same page but by opening the safari browser, if the user is using chrome iOS. Is there a way to do it? I have found this answer([JavaScript for iPhone to open in Safari from non-default iOS browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178610/javascript-for-iphone-to-open-in-safari-from-non-default-ios-browser)) but it seems to be not supported anymore.

Thanks in advance for an answer.