# <form target="_blank"> not working in iOS 7.0.3

Tags: javascript, html, ios, tags, ios7

Following code works perfectly in iOS 6.0.1
(using iOS virtual keyboard, I pressed "Go" button on input box)

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="http://stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">
            <input type="text" />       
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when I tried the exact same code on iOS 7.0.3, this does not work at all.
No response after I press "Go" button on iOS keyboard.

If I remove [target="_blank"] from form tag, then it works properly.

I have no idea what is the reason for this problem.
Does anyone have the same issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Popups are blocked by safari iOS by default.

Disable the block feature by settings -> Safari -> Block Pop-ups.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the HTML is outside of your control, a workaround is to remove the form target property programmatically. Implement the following in your web view delegate:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView
{
        NSString *script = @"for (i=0; i<document.forms.length; i++) { document.forms[i].target = null; }";
        [aWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little jQuery workaround I used to remove the `target="_blank"` attribute on iOS only, on submit:

```
$('#searchform').submit(function(e) {
  if(navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/i)) {
    $(this).removeAttr('target');
  }
});
```

It seems there isn't any better solution as [the solution to transit through a temporary `a` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8833025/3305116) doesn't work on iOS 8+.