# Submit Form With «Go» Button in Safari for iOS

Tags: html, forms, safari

I built a simple form that receive email address which works well in major desktop browsers, however, there is one small problem in Safari for iOS. I can’t submit the form by pressing the **«Go»** button.

Is there any way to submit the form without using any jQuery?

I’ve searched through Stack Overflow on related questions yet still unable to solve this problem.

Here is the code of the form:

```
<form action="http://mailchimp.list.etc" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
  <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" placeholder="Email me when new article is published…" required>
  <input type="submit" class="subscribe" value="Subscribe">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `target="_blank"`. Safari's pop-up blocker doesn't like that.

Remove the `target="_blank"` from your HTML, or see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28807149/594211 for a client-side workaround.