# ipad safari 8.0.2 link unclickable

Tags: javascript, html, ios, safari, popup

Having issue where web links are not 'clickable' anymore on Safari iPad or iPhone since version 8.0.  Works fine on all PC browsers and Android phone.

Running inspect element in Firebug shows that all the `<a />` tags have the `target="_blank"` attribute.  I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19899553/form-target-blank-not-working-in-ios-7-0-3) link that said to turn "Block Pop-ups" off, but that didn't work.  Has anybody else found a solution for this or do I have to replace all the target="_blank" with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

We just recently ran into this problem as well. Safari would set the `a` tag as active but not open the link. All other major browsers worked fine, with Safari on iOS 8 being the only problem child. Even Chrome on iOS 8 behaved as expected.

Our attempts at clearing the browser cache, scrolling up and down, or turning 'Block Pop-ups' off all failed to resolve the issue.

We ended up working around this issue by attaching a click event to all anchors with target="_blank" and opened them via JavaScript. We had jQuery available in our project, so YMMV with the following code:

```
$('a[target="_blank"]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open($(this).attr('href'), $(this).attr('target'));
    return;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but on further experimenting, I think it's actually a webkit bug, as the error starting happening in Android Chrome too after the next update.